# string parsing not working with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to get this right for awhile with no success and would appreciate some help here. Trying to parse out from the string below:

```
LethalWeaponFOX/photos/a.1106081639452035.1073741828.1048614701865396/1234456789011112/?type=3
```

The part I would like to  to remove is last two forward slashes:

1234456789011112

```
pUrl = pUrl.replaceAll("photos\\/.*\\.","");
```

Appreciate suggestions:

EDIT: Sorry I needed to clarify my output and rephrase question

Comment: I just need the values between the last 2 forward slashes

Comment: 1234456789011112; guess I should rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need the values between the last 2 forward slashes `1234456789011112`

In this case you can use this regex `.*\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*$` with [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) :

```
String str = "LethalWea...";
str = str.replaceAll(".*\\/([^\\/]*)\\/[^\\/]*$", "$1");
```

---

#### regex demo

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to split it in this case.

```
    String[] temp = pUrl.split("\\/");
    pUrl = temp[temp.length - 1];
```

Comment: Or `replaceFirst()`.

Comment: thanks; but I think I needed to rephrase the question. I need the value between the last two forward slashes